# iOS : ScrollView delegate method inside of CollectionView not call

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

First I have set **delegate** in **.h file**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UICollectionViewDataSource, UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

After that just call this method in **collection view .m file**

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

    NSLog(@"scrollViewDidScroll");
}
```

but **not call** this method.

Comment: How you add scrollview? programatically? or via xib?

Comment: not add scrollview.It's just default scroll in collection view

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: Have u set collectionview.delegate = self?

Comment: my question is the default scrollView in CollectionView, it delegate not work or call.

Comment: Because no one listening `UIScrollViewDelegate`. Change this code like this: @interface ViewController : UIViewController<UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate> and yourCollectionView.delegate = self;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just do simple

**add below line in** `.m` file

```
yourCollectionView.delegate = self;
```

**and below add in** `.h`

```
UICollectionViewDelegate
```

**remove**

```
UIScrollViewDelegate
```